# How to sort an array with digital size and occurrences

Tags: javascript

I have an array of numbers

```
var number = [7,7,6,9,9,9,3,3]
```

and we want to sort it by number of occurrences.
In this example the result should be:

```
[6,3,3,7,7,9,9,9]
```

We tried to use sort, but couldn't figure it out.
If we only can use sort, how could we solve this problem in one sort?

```
var number = [7,7,6,9,9,9,3,3];
number.sort(function(a,b) {
    //code here
});
```

Comment: return a-b; is the function code you need

Comment: @dandavis - No it's not.

Comment: what's the order based on?

Comment: yep, return can rank by the size,but how about occurrences?

Comment: @dandavis: Says right up there - paraphrased, "we want to sort it by number of occurrences". Also, the expected output is right there.

Comment: first rank by size the result is [3,3,6,7,7,9,9,9] the by occurrences,

Comment: in [3,3,6,7,7,9,9,9] 3*2,6*1,7*2,9*3,so we want the result is 6 > 3 > 7 > 9 that is [6,3,3,7,7,9,9,9]

Comment: Why do the 3s come before the 7s in the result? Should numbers that occur the same number of times be sorted in ascending order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard and inefficient to do it by sort *alone*. You want your frequency counts first.

```
var freq = {};
number.forEach(function(i) {
  freq[i] = (freq[i] || 0) + 1;
})
number.sort(function(a,b) {
  return (freq[a] - freq[b]) || (a - b);
});
// => [6, 7, 7, 3, 3, 9, 9, 9]
```

If you really, really, *really* need it in one function call,

```
number.sort(function(a, b) {
  var afreq = number.filter(function(i) { return i == a; }).length;
  var bfreq = number.filter(function(i) { return i == b; }).length;
  return (afreq - bfreq) || (a - b);
});
```

but as I said above, very, very inefficient.

EDIT: Thanks to Derek 朕會功夫 for golfing it!

EDIT2: Fixed the bug that mixed numbers of same frequency. Thanks again, Derek 朕會功夫!

Comment: It can be even shorter if you do `freq[i] = (freq[i] || 0)+1;`

Comment: This might be a weird bug but it isn't working for `[0,8,6,9,6,6,9,9];` http://jsfiddle.net/2zuasvt8/ but it does work if every number with the same value is next to each other.

Comment: dang, if i'd have known the 7s could come first, i'd have left mine up. good times.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: You're completely correct! If you *only* sort by frequency, all numbers having same frequency would remain in the same relative order. Fixed.

Comment: `(freq[a] - freq[b]) || (a - b)` is brilliant.

Comment: That's what I wanted!